# Dtype error when using Mixed Precision and building EfficientNetB0 Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, efficientnet, automatic-mixed-precision

**System information**

- OS Platform and Distribution : MacOS
- TensorFlow installed from : Colab
- TensorFlow version : 2.5.0
- Python version: python 3.7
- GPU model and memory: Tesla T4

**Error**
`TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Sub' Op has type float16 that does not match type float32 of argument 'x'`

**Current behaviour**

While using Mixed Precision and building a Keras Functional API model (EfficientNet B0), it shows the below error
`TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Sub' Op has type float16 that does not match type float32 of argument 'x'`

> Note : For some reason StackOverflow isn't allowing me to post the images. Visit the below link to get more insight over the issue :
> https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/49725

**Expected behaviour**

The Global Policy I set in the previous cell was `mixed_float16`. The problem works fine when running on `tensorflow 2.4.1` so the bug is with `tensorflow 2.5.0`

You can reproduce the same error using the below notebook :
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1TfNZSIJ_I7IZI35RsGFnTdj-6beMHV2_?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can post your code example and full error traceback as a [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) right in your question. Actually it is a preferred and strongly recommended way for posting code here on SO as the external resources may become invalid in time and it helps other users in searching your question.

Comment: The issue is a bug and you should report it to the main source (not appropriate here in SO).

Comment: Simple [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/49725#issuecomment-848762618) to reproduce the issue.